# Browser does not load when ip address is entered directly into the address bar

Tags: browser, dns, ip

My browsers doesn't load the websites when I put the IP address directly into the address bar. For example, google.com loads perfect, but once I ping and collected the IP address of google.com and pasted it into the address bar, it doesn't get loaded. Am i supposed to imagine this as an error of my DNS server?

I am on an ubuntu machine in a corporate LAN. Please ask if any other information like `hosts` or `resolv.conf` file details needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are entering the IP address directly into the URL bar, DNS should be skipped entirely (since getting the IP address is the whole point of DNS). Are you specifying the port to connect to along with the address? Try the following:

```
#HTTP
http://<IP address>
<IP address>:80

#HTTPS
https://<IP address>
<IP address>:443
```

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes all you need is to try a different browser. install chrome or something and give it a try, it should work and it has nothing to do with your DNS server.

Comment: I have this doubt because, when i checked my `resolve.conf` file under `/etc/`,it shows the name server as `127.0.1.1`. So I believe that my local machine caches the requests and acts as DNS server for my requests. I thought in such a case, it makes the browser to resolve the content(IP) I have entered into the address bar.

Answer (score 0):

The new version of chrome will convert the IPv6 address into a search unless you put brackets around the IPv6 address.  If you want to go directly to the IP try this.

`http://[theipaddress]`

or with a port number

`http://[theipaddress]:PORTNUMBER`

This will also work in Firefox.